# Check all apenas seleciona o primeiro valor do foreach

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boas pessoal, tenho o seguinte codigo, e era suposto ele selecionar todos os valores dentro do foreach, mas em vez de o fazer apenas seleciona o primeiro valor..

Ja tentei fazer um teste de o submit que deleta as cenas so aparecer quando se clica nas checkboxes, mas acontece a mesma coisa, so aparecia se seleccionasse a primeira. Mas se seleccionasse a primeira e mais umas quantas ele apagava na mesma, mas apenas aparecia se a primeira estivesse seleccionada..

```
<form action="" method="post">
<? foreach($itens as $myrow){ ?>
<a href="pagina.php?ID=<? echo $myrow['ID']; ?>"><? echo $myrow['Title']; ?></a>


<? echo $myrow['GDate']; ?>
?>
<? echo $myrow['Hour']; ?>
<div class="dashed-line"></div>
<input name="selector[]" id="testecb" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $myrow['ID']; ?>" />
</div>
</div>
<?}?>
<input type="button" id="selectall-game-button" label="check all" value="Selecionar tudo"
><input type="submit" id="delete-game-button" value="Eliminar" />

<?
****************** AQUI ESTA A ACÇÃO QUE DELETA.. **************
}
} ?>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#selectall-game-button').click(function(){
        var chk = $(this).click('checked')?true:false;
        $('#testecb').attr('checked',chk);
});
```

Alguém tem alguma odeia o porque de isto acontecer? :ss

Comment: `$(this).click('checked')?true:false;` devia ser `.attr()` em vez de `.click()`...

Comment: Na verdade podias simplificar para `$('#testecb').attr('checked', this.checked);` somente.

Comment: @Sergio Poderia, mas isso não não alteraria em nada o estado do checkbox :)

Comment: Sim, porque quero que selecione tudo quando clico no botao ..

Comment: Comece dando um ID diferente para cada checkbox, você não pode repetir IDs no HTML. Se quiser, também pode colocar uma mesma classe em todos para selecionar com mais facilidade no jQuery (mas isso não elimina a necessidade dos IDs únicos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens dois problemas: IDs multiplas e um erro no JS.

**#1** - Não podes usar IDs multiplas neste caso. Classes de CSS é a solução. Isto porque o seletor `$('#testecb')` vai somente retornar o primeiro elemento que encontrar. sugiro usares $('.dashed-line input')

**#2** - No JS tens `$(this).click('checked')` mas esse elemento é um input e não tem `checked`. Imagino então que esse `input type="button"` deva checkar todos os checkboxs...

Assim uma sugestão seria:

```
$('#selectall-game-button').click(function(){
    $('[name="selector[]"]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Repara que esta solução não corrige as IDs multiplas que estás a gerar no PHP. Para corrigir isso podias usar no PHP:

```
<div class="dashed-line"></div>
<input name="selector[]" class="testecb" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $myrow['ID']; ?>" />
</div>
```

e então o seletor já podia ser `$('.testecb').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: Agora nao seleciona nada..

Comment: O que eu quero é selecionar TODAS as checkbox's..

Comment: @thecreator `$('name="selector[]"').prop('checked', this.checked);` faz isso mesmo. Se não estiver a funcionar cria um jsFiddle com o HTML renderizado para ver o teu HTML todo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/262z0jdp/1/

Comment: @thecreator eu pensava que querias selecionar/des-selecionar tudo dependente de uma outra checkbox estar checkada ou não. Se é só um botão que seleciona todas então é mais simple... http://jsfiddle.net/262z0jdp/2/

Comment: E se este botão tiver que des-selecionar também? é possivel fazer? E o botão delete so aparecer quando Alguma checkbox estiver selecionada.. Se me conseguisse ajudar nisso eu agradecia!

Comment: @thecreator pois, essa era mais ou menos a ideia inicial. Algo assim por exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/262z0jdp/3/

Comment: Mas ai o botao de deletar esta sempre visivel, como faço para ficar visivel apenas quando 1 ou mais checkbox estiverem selecionadas?

Comment: @thecreator nesse exemplo a ideia é usar o checkbox para selecionar __e__ para de-selecionar, clicando de novo nele.

Comment: Nao é possivel fazer isto sem ser em checkbox? o selecionar e des-selecionar? Ex: type="button"

Comment: @thecreator sim, é. Queres 3 botões ou só dois? o "Elemminar" é o que de-seleciona?

Comment: Passo a explicar.. Gostaria que o Botao "Selecionar" Fosse mesmo um botão (type="button") e que selecionasse e des-selecionasse. E o botao ELIMINAR só aparecia quando 1 ou mais checkbox's estivessem selecionados..

Comment: @thecreator ok, estou a ver. Então queres algo assim: http://jsfiddle.net/xges18jq/ O "Elemninar" devia estar escondido no CSS no inicio... sabes como fazer isso?

Comment: Siim, `display:none;` Obrigado!

Comment: @thecreator se quiseres podes marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: Desculpe, esqueci-me completamente ! Mais uma vez obrigado por toda a paciencia e por me ter ajudado a resolver isto !